# On Debian (64-bit), how do I install glibc that I built from source?

Tags: debian, glibc

When I tried to do this, my system broke, with every program immediately segfaulting. I believe it's because it installed a new version of `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in `/lib64` but when a program was loaded it would find the old version of `libc.so.6` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` rather than the new version in `/lib64`. (Apparently ld and libc have to match?)

I tried putting `/lib64` at the top of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` and then running `ldconfig`. However, for some reason this didn't fix anything.

Comment: Please explain why you want to install glibc that you built from source.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The answer is pretty stupid: it's because I wanted the ability to trace into C library functions in gdb. It turns out that installing the `libc6-dbg` package wasn't sufficient. Anyway, it works now.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable desire to me. So you want enough debugging/symbol information available to be able to trace C library functions? Why doesn't libc6-dbg work?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I couldn't figure out how to make it work. I installed the package, then I installed a copy of the source tree and configured gdb to search in the source directory. Then I tried to step into `malloc`. It looked for `malloc.c` in the root of the search directory I specified (but of course that's not where it is). I assume that since I rebuilt libc from source, the correct directories are now built into the library, and that's why it works.

Comment: I'm not sure either why it only searched in the root of the search directory, but that actually sounds like a reasonable question for some forum, even this one. You could possibly ask on the glibc or gdb mailing lists. Both of those seem like reasonable places to ask. I generally prefer not to build things from source, particularly  if they are basic packages. It just causes too many problems.

Answer (score 2):

While searching for something unrelated, I fortuitously discovered why my installation was picking up the old libc: because the new libc had an older ABI version (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577638/library-path-order-for-alternate-glibc-dynamic-linker-ld-so).

So this is what I did:

1. I backed up the contents of `/lib`, `/lib32`, and `/lib64`.
2. I edited `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` to place `/lib64` at the top of the search paths.
3. I configured the new version of glibc (2.19) with options `--prefix=/usr --enable-kernel=2.6.26` in order to match the old glibc version (2.13).
4. I built the new glibc. This was uneventful.
5. I used `su` to gain root privileges, and ran `make install`. It started installing, then it segfaulted after the new `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` had been installed and was still picking up the old `libc.so.6`.
6. To fix this, I ran `ldconfig` (still as root of course).
7. I restarted the installation (`make install`). It errored out again on some command that invoked `gcc`. I discovered that this was because of mismatched headers: the new `/usr/include/stdio.h` was picking up the old `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h` rather than the new version at `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h`.
8. So, to fix this, I removed the directory `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys`, and replaced it with a symlink to `/usr/include/sys`. I also replaced the headers `a.out.h`, `fpu_control.h`, and `ieee754.h` in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` with symlinks to their new versions in `/usr/include`.
9. I restarted the installation again (`make install`). Finally it succeeded.

After I rebooted my system, everything was in perfect working order.

I haven't yet found out what happens if I try to also update the 32-bit version of libc installed alongside the 64-bit version on my system. I suspect it will break everything horribly again. Will update this answer if I succeed.